# guard statement in Xcode 13 Why does it will never be executed?

Tags: swift

I have the following code:

```
  private func getDate() async throws -> CurrentDate? {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "someURL") else {
            throw fatalError("URL is incorrect!")
        }
```

On the line throw fataError, the compiler keeps saying "This will never be executed". Why is this? According to my understanding if the URL is not formed correctly then it will never bypass the guard and go to else throwing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `throw` a `fatalError`. Calling `fatalError` stops the execution of your program, it crashes it.

You should create a custom error and throw that instead.

Comment: That is called brain fart. Totally forgot about it.